# How to make a number to the power of a variable

Tags: java, android, math

As above, I'm trying to make a number to the power of a variable, but it's not working, and is producing the error "The operator ^ is undefined for the argument type(s) double, long".

Here's the line of code:

```
longSwordCost = 30*(1.3^longSwordCount);
```

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `public static double Math.pow(double a, double b)`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29

The `^` is an XOR logic operator in Java.